# How can I extract the substring in the last set of parentheses using Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I am using Perl to parse out sizes in a string. What is the regex that I could use to accomplish this:

Example Data:
     Sleepwell Mattress (Twin)
     Magic Nite (Flip Free design) Mattress (Full XL)

Result:
     Twin
     Full XL

I know that I need to start at the end of the string and parse out the first set of parenthesis just not sure how to do it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$file = 'input.csv';

open (F, $file) || die ("Could not open $file!");

while ($line = <F>)
{
  ($field1,$field2,$field3,$field4,$field5,$field6,$field7, $field8, $field9) = split ',', $line;
  if ( $field1 =~ /^.*\((.*)\)/ ) {
  print $1;
}


#print "$field1,$field2,$field3,$field4,$field5,$field6,$field7, $field8, $field9, $1\n";
}

close (F);
```

Not getting any results. Maybe I am not doing this right.

Comment: Whenever you find yourself appending an integer to variable names, realize that you should have used an array in the first place. And, the example data you posted does not match what you seem to be processing in the script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer depends on if the size information you are looking for always appears within parentheses at the end of the string. If that is the case, then your task is simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA> ) {
    last unless /\S/;
    my ($size) = /\( ( [^)]+ ) \)$/x;
    print "$size\n";
}

__DATA__
Sleepwell Mattress (Twin)
Magic Nite (Flip Free design) Mattress (Full XL)
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> xxl
Twin
Full XL
```

Note that the code you posted can be better written as:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my ($input_file) = @ARGV;

open my $input, '<', $input_file
    or die "Could not open '$input_file': $!";

while (my $line = <$input>) {
    chomp $line;
    my @fields = split /,/, $line;
    if ($field[0] =~ /\( ( [^)]+ ) \)$/x ) {
        print $1;
    }
    print join('|', @fields), "\n";
}

close $input;
```

Also, you should consider using [Text::xSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text::xSV) or [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text::CSV_XS) to process CSV files.

Answer (score 2):

The following regular expression will match the content at the end of the string:

```
m/\(([^)]+)\)$/m
```

The m at then end matches mutli-line strings and changes the $ to match at the end of the line, not the end of the string.

[edited to add the bit about multi-line strings]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data arrives line by line, and you are only interested in the contents of the last set of parens:

```
if ( $string =~ /^.*\((.*)\)/ ) {
  print $1;
}
```

Comment: Although it doesn't hurt, the ^ is useless if you start your regex with .*

Answer (score 0):

fancy regex is not really necessary here. make it easier on yourself. you can do splitting on "[space](" and get the last element. Of course, this is when the data you want to get is always at the last...and have parenthesis

```
while(<>){
    @a = split / \(/, $_;
    print $a[-1]; # get the last element. do your own trimming
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the answer as expressed in Perl5:

```
my $str = "Magic Nite (Flip Free design) Mattress (Full XL)";
$str =~ m/.*\((.*)\)/;
print "$1\r\n";
```